# procedure in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

i am facing a little problem with this question.. i have done what i know 
Help if you can

a)  Create a procedure ‘insert_History’ that inserts a new record into the ‘History’ table.
b)  Write a small PL/SQL program that calls the "insert_History"  procedure to insert the three records based on the facts given below:

i.  Mark jackop  hired 01/05/2009 as ‘SH-CLERK’  got a new position of a sales representative (Job_ID = ‘SA-REP’) on 04/06/2009. Assume that the end date for the previous position is ‘31/05/2009’.

table: history---> emp_id , start_date , end_date , job_id, dep_id
table: employee ----> emp_id , name,job_id,dep_id

this what i have done !

```
create or replace
procedure insert_History(emp_id in integer , job_id in number) 
is 
begin 
update History
set ?????? = insert into history(.....) 
where employees.emp_id= emp_id;
end;
```

Comment: Please tag homework questions as homework

Comment: It is not a home work. It is just a revision question

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "a revision question".

Comment: Forgive me for doubting you, but a review of your posts to date show that every question you've asked on this site appears to be related to school work.  It's OK to ask homework questions, but A) it's best not to try to disguise it; people here are professional developers; we have done our share of homework questions in our time and we do recognize them when we see them, and B) you're going to have to post something that shows you really tried, not just some "pretend" code that has no chance of ever having been run.

Comment: [homework] means any question coming from an educational intent, which definition clearly extends to "revision". Personally, I think posting homework questions on SO is less immoral than people taking money from their employers to write programs when they can't code their way out of a wet paper bag. Nevertheless, if you rely on us to write a solution instead of actually trying to solve it yourself you will never learn anything.

Comment: My friend.  Simply, no need to answer the question. Do not bother and write this paragraph

Comment: The purpose of SO is to provide a resource of helpful answers to interesting questions for the benefit of the broader programming community. Your question is not a question. Rather it is a request for somebody to write a trivial piece of PL/SQL which you apparently are too lazy to figure out for yourself.

Comment: You are right: we're all volunteers here and devote our time as we wish.  I have chosen to explain StackOverflow to you, and to suggest you will learn more from wrestling with problems thanfrom  being spoonfed answers.  Likewise you may choose to think I'm being annoying rather than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

first i would be putting your work into packages as that keeps things organized, easier to read/call, and makes it a hell of a lot easier to go back and remember how things worked ( cause i know after not looking at a procedure for months i'll forget what exactly it does.) i could image the nightmare it would be to try and reverse engineer someone's code when its all just piled into procedures with little to no explanation as how it works. You wouldn't just create a java/oop program all in one class!

Also a side note, using packages is just a good practice to get into the habit of doing as well as making sure you comment the crap out of your code to explain what it does.

note it seems and correct me if i'm wrong the directions want you to **insert** not update 3 records. Also it seems to want more than just the emp_id and job_id (start and end dates as well as dep_id. So these values need to be obtained by the procedure.

```
  create or replace
    PACKAGE "history" AS 
       procedure insert_history(pEmp_id integer, pstart_date date, pend_date date, pJob_id number, pdep_id);
    end history;

create or replace 
package body "history" as 
 procedure insert_history(pEmp_id in integer, pstart_date in date, pend_date in date,               pJob_id in number, pdep_id in number)
 is 
 begin
   insert into history(emp_id , start_date , end_date , job_id, dep_id)
   values(pEmp_id, pstart_date, pend_date, pJob_id, pdep_id );
   commit;
 end insert_history;
```

and that's pretty much it for the insert procedure. Now you need something that will call this procedure. Here i'm assuming you're getting these dates from an application or higher level in the application and thus the start and end dates, and emp name are coming in as parameters.
so we'll just create this as and outstanding procedure.

```
create or replace procedure call_insert_history(Pemp_name in varchar2(256), varchar2(256), Pstart_date in date, Pend_date in date)
is
Vemp_id number;
Vdep_id number;
Vjob_id number;
begin
--first get the emp_id, dep_id, job_id
select emp_id, dep_id, job_id into Vemp_id, Vdep_id, Vjob_id from employees where emp_name = Pemp_name;
--now call the insert_history procedure using the obtained variables.
history.insert_history(Vemp_id, Pstart_date, Pend_date, Vjob_id, Vdep_id);
end call_insert_history;
```

and that should be it.

**note:**

This is just my best guess and i have not tested it. I'm just going off what i understand from the fairly vague directions. If you are not getting those values from an application then you would have to store each value and then call the rest of the above procedure without using parameters.

Hope this helps or at least points you in the right direction!